# How to create a Complete Binary Tree in Java

Tags: java, queue, binary-tree, nodes

What is an easy implementation of a complete binary tree. The values wouldn't influence the order on which they are set into the tree. What is listed below is ideal.

```
        A
      /   \
     B     C
    / \   / \
   D   E F   G
```

How would one code it this way with say a queue?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Some what. Since my question was pretty general, I guess I get a general answer. That was my fault. It turns out what I need is not just a general tree, but a Heap as well. 

I figured it out though, Thanks for your input, I'll mark as answer when i can

Comment: @10111110 you have a priviledge to upvote. Would you? Just for your personal development I recommend [ask] and [mcve] as they help not receiving downvotes on questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your BST should look like the following. I'll skip method bodies ofc. You can either have two different classes - for root and for nodes or not. I'll show you the pattern for one class implementation.

```
public class BinarySearchTreeNode<T extends Comparable<T>>{

    private T value;
    private BinarySearchTreeNode<T> left;
    private BinarySearchTreeNode<T> right;

    public BinarySearchTreeNode<T> insert(T t) {
        //your implementation here
    }
    public BinarySearchTreeNode<T> find(T t) {
        //your implementation here
    }
    public BinarySearchTreeNode<T> delete(T t) {
        //your implementation here
    }
    public void display(){
        //your implementation here
    }

    //getters, setters
}
```

You will need:

- Some knowledge about [Java Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/),
- Basic knowledge about [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html),
- Introduction to algorithms by Cormen or [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) *pardon me, it might be even linked wikipedia*.

I have attached links to Java documentation and Wikipedia for your comfort. Just in case you still can't write your BST, simply ask for clarification in a comment. Please be specific enough, so I know what your doubt is about.